# Right Align an inline UL which is inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a pagination output which is show within

. An example is posted here: http://jsfiddle.net/6N4bD/1/

The ul is wrapped around 2 divs

1st div is 550 width
2nd div called "paginationDiv" basically wraps the ul around

The ul has list-style: none. What I am trying to do is make it float right, but it keeps appearing as a block. I have tried quite a few things but nothing seems to work. If I add a width to the paginationDiv then it works but it's not accurate because it will never be fixed width

Here is what it looks like:

```
<div class="parentDiv">
   <div class="paginationDiv">
      <ul id="paginationLinks">
        <li>Page 1</li>
        <li>Page 2</li>
      </ul> 
    </div>
 </div>
```

That's the html code

Here is the css:

```
div.parentDiv { 
  width: 550px; 
}
div.paginationDiv {
  float: right;
}
#paginationLinks ul {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#paginationLinks li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

I have posted an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6N4bD/1/

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It seems to be working in my browser (Opera 11).

Comment: @Exelian: You're right, it already worked in Opera. However, you should know that statistically, he's probably testing in Firefox or IE.

Comment: I tested in IE7, IE8, Firefox, and Chrome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

give `float:left` to `#paginationLinks li` and then see the result

Comment: Thanks, I added your code along with @Chris's code (display: inline;)

Comment: Of course you'll need to reverse the display order too.

Answer (score 9):

What seems to work is adding `display: inline;` to the li elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/XFdqT/ has a demo of this.

Comment: Thanks, I added your code along with @Mahima's code (float: left;)